# ngMockE2E does not work with remote Selenium server

Tags: angularjs, cucumber, protractor

**Setup**

We use protractor, protractor-cucumber, and angular-mocks to handle our e2e tests. Builds are managed by grunt.

We have two build configs; `pool` and `local`. `pool` is the configuration that is picked up by our CI environment, `local` is for debugging purposes and is setup to run on a local machine. *The primary difference between the two setups is that `local` runs everything locally, whereas `pool` uses a remote Selenium server (outside the CI server itself)*.

protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  params: {
    widgetUrl: 'http://localhost:9980',
    vudUrl: 'xxx',
    testDelay: 3000,
  },

  // The timeout for each script run on the browser. This should be longer
  // than the maximum time your application needs to stabilize between tasks.
  allScriptsTimeout: 150000,

  // A base URL for your application under test. Calls to protractor.get()
  // with relative paths will be prepended with this.
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || '9082'),

  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  specs: ['./e2e/features/*.feature'],

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./e2e/steps/*.js', './e2e/pageObjects/*.js', './e2e/support/*.js'],
    format: 'pretty',
    tags: ['@context-test']
  },

  // Patterns to exclude.
  exclude: [],

  // ----- Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance ----
  //
  // For a full list of available capabilities, see
  // https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities
  // and
  // https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/capabilities.js
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    loggingPrefs: {
      'driver': 'INFO',
      'server': 'INFO',
      'browser': 'INFO'
    }
  },

  // ----- The test framework -----
  //
  // Jasmine and Cucumber are fully supported as a test and assertion framework.
  // Mocha has limited beta support. You will need to include your own
  // assertion framework if working with mocha.
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: 'node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework',

  mocks: {
    dir: "mocks",  // path to directory with mocks
    default: []
  },

  onPrepare: function() {

    // Chai config
    var chai = require('chai');
    var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    global.expect = chai.expect;

    console.log('params: ' + JSON.stringify(browser.params));
    //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }
};
```

We configure our mocks in a `Before` hook (snipped here for brevity):

```
 this.Before(function(scenario, callback) {

    // ...

    let data = require(`${TEST_DATA_DIR}/default.js`);
    let httpMocker = function() {
      angular.module('httpMocker', ['ngMockE2E'])
        .run(function($httpBackend) {
          $httpBackend.whenPOST(...);
    };
    browser.addMockModule('httpMocker', httpMocker, {data})

    // ...

    callback();
  });
```

**Problem**

Despite identical test setups, `ngMockE2E` is *not* being called when run in the CI environment. This can be demonstrated by the following test:

test.feature:

```
@Test
Feature: Test and debug

  @context-test
  Scenario: Get console output
    Given I access the page
    Then I get the log output
```

test.steps.js

```
module.exports = function() {

  this.Given(/^I access the page$/, () => {
    util.waitAndDo(() => true);
  });

  this.Then(/^I get the log output$/, () => {
    util.waitAndDo(() => {
      browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
        console.log('log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
      });
    })
  });
};
```

This test will dump the browser log rather than actually testing anything. When it is run locally, the logs are empty. *However*, when the same test is run in the CI environment, the logs show errors for failed calls to the URLs being mocked.

We have verified that the URLs used in the CI environment correctly match the regex in our mocks, so it is not a match-miss. The module is simply not being called.

To reiterate - the only major difference in configuration is that the `pool` config makes use of a remote Selenium hub. How could this affect how our tests are run, and why would it prevent our mocks from working?

Comment: When you run remotly and the selenium tries to access `http://localhost` what do you think it's going to see? You have to specify address on which remote machine can access your webapp i.e. `http://192.168.0.77` where the IP is your machine IP

Comment: That's a default value, we set the specific value in the grunt config. I didn't want to include it since it is basically just a bunch of environment variables whose values I am not allowed to share due to my contract. The only relevant takeaway is that one config uses a remote Selenium server, and the other just runs everythign on the local machine.

Comment: Please double check that you call the right endpoint, the only reason I can think of is that the resources are unreachable

Comment: Double and triple checked already. Endpoints are being properly called and logs generated. The mocked module simply never gets invoked

Comment: what if you add `127.0.0.1 foo.com` to your hosts file and try running tests with `http://foo.com` instead of localhost?

Comment: @csvan, were you ever able to solve this?  Running into the exact same issue now